# ¿Cómo puedo arreglar el error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer"?

Tags: c++

Al querer hacer un convertidor de binario a Hexadecimal, en el case 1 me manda el error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer" quisiera saber cual es el problema ahi o si no lo tengo que hacer con arreglos?

```
cout <<"INGRESE EL NUMERO BINARIO: "<<endl;
        cin>>binario;
        cout<<endl;
        
        if (digito==0 | digito==1)
        {
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            digito[i] = binario % 10;
            binario /= 10;
        }
        for (int i=7; i>=0; i--)
        {
            resultado = (resto * 2) + digito[i];
            resto = resultado;
        }
        ltoa (resultado, cadena, 16);
        cout<<"EL NUMERO DE BINARIO A HEXADECIMAL ES: "<<cadena<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        }
        break;
```

Me manda error al compilar en el if de digito==0 | digito==1 quisiera como solucionar eso si es posible

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo deducir, `digito` es un arreglo o un puntero; sin embargo intentas compararlo con un número.

```
if (digito==0 | digito==1)
```

No sé cuál es tu cometido con esa línea de código pero los punteros también son números. Así que puedes forzar al compilador a compilar con una conversión explícita:

```
(unsigned long long)digito == 0
```

O al estilo de C++:

```
static_cast<unsigned long long>(digito) == 0
```

Es importante que el tipo numérico que utilices sea del mismo tamaño que el puntero y sin signo.